# Selenium "No such element error" but the element is found

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am writing a selenium webscraper and I have encountered an issue in which Selenium tells me that there was no such element found on the webpage, however the element is supposed to be clicked on and it gets clicked on. To my understanding this should be impossible since the element was not found. This is the webpage that I am trying to scrape [https://www.sreality.cz/adresar/mm-reality-praha-nove-mesto/1019]. I am trying to scrape the company title at the top, the number of offers in the button, the address, the phone number and the email. The thing is in order to view the phone number and the email address you first have to click on the text and then it gets revealed. The approach that I am trying now is to find the element - click on it - save the information into the variable. As I understand it this is where the error happens. But when I run the code the elements are revealed and so the click must have happened but then the program ends and tells me that the element was not found.  This is the code that I am having trouble with :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import time
import csv

path = "/home/user/Projects/Scraper/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.sreality.cz/adresar/mm-reality-praha-nove-mesto/1019")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

with open('SRealityDetails.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

while True:
    try:
        information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ng-binding")))
        for item in information_list:
            title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/h1/span[2]""")
            offers = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.switcher.ng-binding.ng-scope span.ng-binding.ng-scope")
            addresses = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td""")
            phone_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.value.link.ng-binding.ng-scope")
            phone_number.click()
            phone_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.phone.ng-binding")
            email = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.value.link.ng-binding")
            email.click()
            email = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.value.link.ng-binding")
            print(title, " ", offers, " ", addresses, " ", phone_number, " ", email)
        time.sleep(10)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

This is the error output :

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"button.value.link.ng-binding.ng-scope"}
> (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Unfortunately the program doesn't want to continue once the "No such element found" error passes through. I can't figure out why this error happens and I would be grateful if someone could explain to me how does this happen and what I am doing wrong. Thanks to anyone.

Comment: Post the full traceback so that we can see which line raises the exception.

Comment: The traceback unfortunately doesn't contain which line caused the exception. It seems like that Selenium only tells you the line in some cases. However this is the information that I get :

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button.value.link.ng-binding.ng-scope"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)


Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: phone_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.value.link.ng-binding.ng-scope") is the problem line. You haven't used any waits so it might not get the element.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things about your code:

**Firstly**, maybe you are trying to print the text the elements extracted above. Use `text` with elements while printing them.Like this,

```
print(title.text, " ", offers.text, " ", addresses.text, " ", phone_number.text, " ", email.text)
```

**Secondly**, `Process finished with exit code 0` means, there is no error with your code. Your code is working fine. The stacktrace your are getting is being printed just because you are printing `e`. Now why is it being printed, the reason is unknown because if the element would have not found, it wont be able to click on the element.

Just try removing the print(e) in except block.

**Thirdly**, you have initialized WebDriverWait in the script but not using it while extracting elements from webpage, use that while extracting the elements, it will be more easy and effective.